# Unable to use instance of IEditorPart (Eclipse text editor) in JavaFX application

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a plugin whereby when a handler is called an instance of IEditorPart is instantiated with the current editor which is the eclipse text editor in this context.

```
editor = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
```

This instance is passed to a JavaFX application.  Before `Application.launch()` is called there is access to this instance of the eclipse text editor, however, after it is called a null pointer exception occurs when trying to use it.

Does this instance get removed when the JavaFX application enters its life-cycle?  Is there anyway to use this instance as it is a vital element in the plugin as I am using tables and when an element of the table is clicked, the eclipse editor is brought into scope and then this element clicked is wrote to the screen.

I am aware the eclipse text editor is SWT therefore there may be complications using both SWT and JavaFX together.  Any ideas?  I can post full code if the question is too ambiguous.

Comment: When posting about an exception, stack traces help greatly. Please add one.

Comment: You may be better off asking the [e(fx)clipse community](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/community.html) this question rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: `Application.launch()` creates the application instance on it's own, which could be the issue, if the value is stored in a non-static field. A workaround for only being able to start a single application could be even harder.